# Call Silverlight with Javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I'm trying to call a public method of a silverlight app via javascript that simply sets a private variable.  When I attempt to set the file name, I get a javascript error.  fu.Content.myObject is undefined.  Can anyone spot the error?  http://www.devicity.com/fileuploadertestpage.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>FileUploader</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#silverlightControlHost {
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
        var appSource = "";
        if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
          appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
        }

        var errorType = args.ErrorType;
        var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

        if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
          return;
        }

        var errMsg = "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " +  appSource + "\n" ;

        errMsg += "Code: "+ iErrorCode + "    \n";
        errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
        errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

        if (errorType == "ParserError") {
            errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
        }
        else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {           
            if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Position: " +  args.charPosition + "     \n";
            }
            errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
        }

        throw new Error(errMsg);
    }
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SetFileName() {
        var fu = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
        fu.Content.myObject.SetFileName("10");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," id="FileUpload1" type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="600" height="600">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/FileUploader.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
    <input type="button" onclick="SetFileName();" value="SetFileName" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

``

```
[ScriptableType]
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("myObject", this);

    }

    private string m_FileName = "setthis";

    [ScriptableMember]
    public void SetFileName(string fileName)
    {
        m_FileName = fileName;
    }

    private OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    private void Browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        dlg.Multiselect = false;
        dlg.Filter = "MP3s (*.mp3)|*.mp3|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        bool? retval = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (retval != null && retval == true)
        {

            StatusText.Text = dlg.File.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            StatusText.Text = "No file selected...";
        }
    }

    private void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream data)
    {
        UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:43439/uploadfile.aspx");
        ub.Query = string.Format("filename={0}", m_FileName);

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        c.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            PushData(data, e.Result);
            e.Result.Close();
            data.Close();
        };
        c.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri);
    }

    private void Upload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            UploadFile(StatusText.Text, dlg.File.OpenRead());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusText.Text = ex.ToString();
        }

    }



    private void PushData(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        int totalBytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            StatusText.Text = ((int)(totalBytesRead / input.Length)).ToString("P");
            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you don't capitalize `Content` in the Javascript `SetFileName` function?

```
fu.content.myObject.SetFileName("10");
```

That's the only obvious difference I see between what my program and your code are doing to call into a Silverlight object.

Comment: Nope, same issue, although IE gives "Unspecified Error" and firefox is an undefined object.  http://www.devicity.com/fileuploadertestpage.aspx